# What is the expiry time of bigcommerce access tokens?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have created a app in bigcommerce and authenticated through oauth and also got an access tokens. But I am not sure about the expiry time of the access token.

Answer (score 0):

There's no expiry set until the user uninstalls your app.

- If the user hits the /uninstall endpoint and you've never made any calls using the access token, the access token will expire immediately.
- If the user hits the /uninstall endpoint and you've made at least one call using the access token, the access token will expire after an hour.
  This grace period is designed to allow apps to remove any content they might have added to the store when the user has unsubscribed.